# How to get the primary key of the last row inserted into the table

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, multiview

I am using multiview index to insert the news details. In the first view the user can enter details of news which is then inserted into db on clicking the next button
the second view gives a user to add images of that news (only 3 images allowed) ,

what I am having problem is that the first view inserts data into the table dbo.newsdetail with a primary key
newsID , while the second view should add the respected images using that newsId of the news just added into newsimages table. I just dont know how to get the newsID of the details
which is added in the first view as news Id is working as a foreign key for the both the table. Any help or suggestions will be highly appreciated .

```
 static public void insertNews(string newsDescription, string newsImage, string newsTitle)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand insertNews = new SqlCommand("Insert INTO caravanNews(newsDescription, newsImage, newsTitle) VALUES ('" + newsDescription + "', '" + newsImage + "' , '" + newsTitle + "')",conn);
    insertNews.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

}
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? With PostgreSQL you could use `INSERT ... RETURNING ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A separate SQL statement

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Or the [OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

```
INSERT MyTable (...=
OUTPUT INSERTED.KeyCol
VALUES (...) --Or SELECT ... FROM Another table)
```

Edit:

- change your insert statement to match mine
- change .ExecuteNonQuery() to blah = xxx.ExecuteScalar()

Comment: i need to save that ID to be used another method in code behind , i have edited the code can you provide me with the query plz

Answer (score 0):

As part of your INSERT statement (into the first News table), after it runs, execute

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

and return `NewsId` value to caller.

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx).

Comment: i need to save that ID to be used another method in code behind , i have edited the code can you provide me with the query plz