# Getting Identity Column Value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, identity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the primary key of the last row inserted into the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962322/how-to-get-the-primary-key-of-the-last-row-inserted-into-the-table)

In SQL Server 2008, I have a stored proc that inserts in a table which includes identity column for ID. I need to return the ID of record to my application so that I can use it for related tables.

How can I get generated ID by SQL?

Answer (score 2):

Use `select Scope_Identity()` to get the ID

Answer (score 2):

A separate SQL statement

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Or the [OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

```
INSERT MyTable (...=
OUTPUT INSERTED.KeyCol
VALUES (...) --Or SELECT ... FROM Another table)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options that are a bit different:

- [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) - that's what I would use
- [IDENT_CURRENT( 'table_name' )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx)
- [@@IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx)

Comment: There is a risk that: Between insert operation and executing SCOPE_IDENTITY(), stored proc may be executed again for a new record. So the SCOPE_IDENTITY() will tell incorect value.

Comment: No the risk you mention is not there. Each call to the stored procedure will be in a different scope. Scope_Identity() will return the correct ID value that corresponds to the stored procedure called.

Comment: @Ahmet Altun: SCOPE_IDENTITY is the only safe way to get the ID value. The "SCOPE" bit ensures that