# Procedure "Assigning values issue"

Tags: sql-server, identity, procedure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the primary key of the last row inserted into the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962322/how-to-get-the-primary-key-of-the-last-row-inserted-into-the-table)

I have 2 tables:

```
Downloaded(Id,MovieName,DownloadedBy)
Movie(ID,Rating,...)
```

`Downloaded(id)` is `identity (1,1)` and the `Movie(Id)` is foreign key to `Downloaded(id)`
now i need to do procedure for inserting in both at the same time

```
alter proc sp_Insert
@name varchar (50),
@year int,
@type varchar (50),
@rating int,
@available bit
AS
Insert into Downloaded (MovieName) values (@name)
declare @id int
select Id=@id
from Downloaded
where MovieName=@name
Insert into Movie values (@id,@year,@type,@rating,@available)
```

Now my problem is that from `SELECT` the `@id` takes the `null` value from `id` which means the `Downloaded(id)` didn't take the new identity value.

So what to do in order to make `@id` take the identity value of `id` is there any kind of executing in blocks or i dont know maybe transaction

please be patient with me, I'm still new at this

Comment: I feel stupid!! its just select @id=id nvm